# W and its Orthogonal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how to connect intersection and orthogonal complements.

Specifically I need to prove that $X\cap X^\perp = \{\vec{0}\}$. I am given that $W$ is a subspace of $R^n$.

Any help you can give me would be helpful thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in X$ and $w\in X^\perp,$ then $x\cdot w=0.$

So every element $x$ of $X\cap X^{\perp}$ satisfies $x\cdot x = 0.$ When is $x\cdot x=0?$

Comment: $x \bullet x=0$ will be true as long as $x=0$ by definition of orthogonal. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: In order to prove they are equal I know I have to prove they are a subspace of each other

Comment: Not really. You have to prove that if $x\in X\cap X^{\perp}$ iff $x=0.$ We've shown that $x\in X\cap X^{\perp}$ then $x\cdot x=0.$